# Can individual Composer dependencies be suppressed from (auto)loading?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project containing, amongst others, the following `composer.json` dependencies:

```
"propel/propel1": "dev-master"`,
"halleck45/phpmetrics": "dev-master"
```

I recently did a `composer update` and found that a new version of a library required by PhpMetrics, called Hoa, introduces a new class `\EngineException` to emulate a new PHP7 class. Unfortunately Propel 1 also defines `\EngineException`, and so a conflict results.

The correct fix for this would be to upgrade to Propel 2, which uses namespaces. However this is still in alpha and is subject to BC breaks, so is not really workable for me.

My present fix is to lock Hoa to a specific version that does not have the new class:

```
"hoa/core": "2.15.04.*"
```

That's not a bad solution, but it isn't entirely satisfying to lock a library to an old version.

In the Hoa code, the only way for the new class not to be loaded is to be running PHP 7, which is again not feasible. However, it also occurs to me that Hoa only needs to be `require`d when PhpMetrics runs. This is a stand-alone code analysis tool and only sits in the root of the project for convenience; the rest of the project does not use this library.

Thus, it would be great if I could call something in Composer to ask that this class is not (auto)loaded, or perhaps something to do the same in the `composer.json`. It is being needlessly loaded at present - I don't know whether it is being autoloaded incorrectly or whether it is being `require`d manually by Composer.

It may help to know that Hoa classes have been added by Composer to the auto-generated `autoload_psr4.php` script. As far as I can [understand the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4), this means it is autoloaded, and there is nothing in my project that would require any of the Hoa classes.

Comment: It depends on how the class is autoloaded. Normal autoloading should do no harm, as it should stop after the class has been found once, assuming both provide the same functionality. If, however, the file is being autoloaded with the "file" autoloader, then there is not much you can do. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: Thanks @Bert. Your comment inclines me to think that Hoa's approach is broken: the `\EngineException` class [appears in a file called Consistency.php](https://github.com/hoaproject/Core/blob/2.15.07.05/Consistency.php#L952), so the exception class is loaded whether I like it or not. However, I don't know what forces Consistency.php to load - that simply is not required by my project.

Comment: @AlokRaj: I have [reviewed your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29401334), and found that it corrupted the grammatical meaning. The phase "does not have the new class" contained the definite article deliberately - it is referring to a _specific_ class, not any/general one, which was your meaning.

Comment: The phrase "sits in the root" seems to be fine, since things are in folders, not at folders. I suppose "sits at the root" would be OK, but it is not in any reasonable sense an improvement.

Comment: My advice to you is that if you are not completely familiar with English, editing is probably not for you. Indeed, retaliatory editing is also not a good motivation for improving posts. I do accept changes to my material, but given that I am an experienced editor, you can assume that the grammatical quality needs to be exceptional for the new version to be an improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious, so I looked it up. Hoa indeed has a broken approach, having the file `Core.php` always included, by a ["file" autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) in composer which in turn includes `Consistency.php`. The latter defines your class.

You could raise an issue with the developers at Hoa, to use [`class_exists`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) to check for the method rather than the currection version check they are using. This could cause the propel autoloader to load its own. Another way would be to define their autoloading correctly, but they prefer to load manually as it seems.

Comment: Aha, good spot! Since `Core` appears in `autoload_psr4.php`, I didn't think it would appear in `autoload_files.php` as well. Nice work, I will raise a ticket with them to see if they can swap to a proper autoloading approach.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by https://github.com/hoaproject/Core/commit/8ed00fe9345c4f8b2679a256926d6d24994ea842.

> The new exception architecture introduced in PHP7 [1] has been totally
>   redesigned [2]. This patch updates the retro-compatibility classes
>   according to this new architecture. Consequently, the `BaseException`
>   class has been removed, along with `EngineException` and
>   `ParseException`. While these latters could be implemented (not as
>   is), we prefer to, so far, only implement the `Throwable` interface.
>   Let see if we can implement (still for the retro-compatibility) the
>   `Error`, `TypeError` and `ParseError` class.
>
> [1]: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7
>
> [2]: rfc/throwable-interface